Is Root Logger At Logging Module?
Although my this question seems trivial, but it really makes me doubt is this due to Python documentation mistake or my understanding has some issues ?
When I reading Python's logging documentation, I met this statement:

By default, no destination is set for any logging messages. You can
specify a destination (such as console or file) by using basicConfig()
as in the tutorial examples. If you call the functions debug(),
info(), warning(), error() and critical(), they will check to see if
no destination is set; and if one is not set, they will set a
destination of the console (sys.stderr) and a default format for the
displayed message before delegating to the root logger to do the
actual message output.

This is a confusion to me, since here debug(), info() ... etc. function is referring to the ones on the logging module(not on logging.Logger instances), and they are just a syntactic sugar for calling Logger.debug() on root logger according to the documentation of logging.debug(). Since above quoted states "before delegating to the root logger", I wonder here the debug() method is already called on the root logger, how can it delegating to the "root logger" any more ?

The logging.debug() etc. are not methods, they are functions with the same names as the methods on loggers.

I reread the documentation of logging.debug, from below;

logging.debug(msg, *args, **kwargs) This is a convenience function
that calls Logger.debug(), on the root logger. The handling of the
arguments is in every way identical to what is described in that
method.
The only difference is that if the root logger has no handlers, then
basicConfig() is called, prior to calling debug on the root logger.

when you read "if the root logger has no handlers, then basicConfig() is called, prior to calling debug on the root logger", thus you can see the logging.debug is called on the root logger. The basicConfig function is making a StreamHandler and adds it to the root logger from its documentation.
